# how to get json object out of django paginator value

Tags: python, django

am trying to get a Json value out of Django Paginator object so that i can return it back to html file as a json response via JsonResponse method.Please help
Heres my Code

```html
users=User.objects.all().order_by("id")
book_paginator=Paginator(users,10)
page_num=request.GET.get('page') // say page==2
page=book_paginator.get_page(page_num)
retutn JsonResponse({'data':page)
```

I know it wont work but you get the point of what am trying to archieve. Please help Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate the `get_page()` result

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

pages = book_paginator.get_page(page_num)
data = [model_to_dict(page) for page in pages]
return JsonResponse({'data': data)
```